# Почему curl не отправляет двойные кавычки в powershell?

Tags: curl, cmd, powershell

Я написал простой эхо-сервер. Когда я пытаюсь отправить на него запрос через curl из powershell (не Invoke-Webrequest, а нормальный курл) с двойными кавычками ("), то он их пропускает:

```
PS Z:\code\qwe42> '"hello world!"'
"hello world!"
PS Z:\code\qwe42> curl localhost:4215/echo -d '"hello world!"'
hello world!
PS Z:\code\qwe42> curl localhost:4215/echo -d "`"hello world!`"" # то же, но с экранированием
hello world!
```

Однако, когда я отправляю такой же запрос из cmd, то всё отправляется нормально:

```
Z:\code\qwe42>curl localhost:4215/echo -d "\"hello world!\""
"hello world!"
```

Curl версии 7.80._02, powershell 5.1 (build 19041), win 10 x64

Comment: curl в PS является алиасом для Invoke-Webrequest, чтобы запустить системный curl.exe указывайте полный путь к исполняемому файлу.

Comment: @user7860670 я в вопросе написал про то, что у меня курл обычный. в $profile у меня удаляется алиас, а curl.exe закинут в C:\Windows\. Проверка: invoke-webrequest без аргументов начинает писать "Командлет Invoke-WebRequest в конвейере команд в позиции 1", а curl без аргументов — "curl: try 'curl --help' for more information"

Comment: Т.е. это вы сами добавили еще один исполняемый файл curl в C:\Windows\? А случаем не получается так, что в одном случае curl вызывается системный, а в другом - ваш? Попробуйте все-таки указать полный путь.

Comment: @user7860670 результат такой же, вызывается один и тот же бинарник

Comment: А ничего, что кавычки по разному экранируются?

Comment: @KoVadim в powershell и cmd экранирование делается по-разному

Comment: Проблема решилась. Выяснилось, что требуется удваивать или утраивать кавычки. В майкрософте, судя по всему, работают очень весёлые люди :D

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась. Выяснилось, что требуется удваивать или утраивать кавычки. В майкрософте, судя по всему, работают очень весёлые люди :D